# Add vertical line to plot in R

Tags: r, date, plot

I would like to add vertical lines to the plot in the beginning of years 2020 and 2022. I think the problem might be related with the Date format

My data looks like this:

```r
dput(plot_data2)
structure(list(Date = structure(c(1640995200, 1648771200, 1656633600, 
1664582400, 1672531200, 1680307200, 1688169600), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), Index = c(1.159, 1.19, 1.2, 1.203, 1.203, 1.212, 
1.218), Compensation = c(0.667, 0.674, 0.682, 0.685, 0.694, 0.702, 
0.704), Depreciation = c(0.174, 0.178, 0.181, 0.184, 0.186, 0.189, 
0.189), Taxes = c(0.107, 0.11, 0.109, 0.109, 0.11, 0.109, 0.109
), Interest = c(0.027, 0.026, 0.025, 0.023, 0.022, 0.019, 0.015
), Corpotaxes = c(0.038, 0.038, 0.036, 0.037, 0.038, 0.038, 0.038
), Profits = c(0.147, 0.165, 0.167, 0.164, 0.153, 0.156, 0.162
), Profitshare = c(0.125970664365833, 0.13781512605042, 0.139166666666667, 
0.13715710723192, 0.127182044887781, 0.127887788778878, 0.133825944170772
), InterestTaxesCounter = c(0.13, 0.143, 0.142, 0.142, 0.143, 
0.142, 0.142), Counterfactual = c(0.129421915444349, 0.131932773109244, 
0.1325, 0.12884455527847, 0.118038237738986, 0.116336633663366, 
0.119047619047619)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```r
plot_data2 <- 
  subset(indexprofitshare, Date >= as.Date("2018-01-01"))

plot(plot_data2$Date, plot_data2$Profitshare,
     type = "l", yaxt = "n", col = "blue",
     xlab = "Date", ylab = "Value", ylim = c(0.05, 0.15)
  )

lines(
  indexprofitshare$Date[indexprofitshare$Date >= as.Date("2020-01-01")],
  indexprofitshare$Counterfactual[indexprofitshare$Date >= as.Date("2020-01-01")],
  type = "l", col = "red", lty = 2
  )

legend("bottomright",
       legend = c("Profitshare", "Counterfactual"),
       col = c("blue", "red"), lty = c(1, 2)
  )

axis(side = 2, at = pretty(c(0.06,0.14)), 
     labels = paste0(pretty(c(0.06,0.14) * 100), '%'),
     las = 1
  )

abline(v = c(as.Date("2022-01-01"), as.Date("2022-01-01")), 
       col = c("blue", "red"), lty = c(1,2), lwd = c(1, 3))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using abline() when x-axis is date (ie, time-series data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21228272/using-abline-when-x-axis-is-date-ie-time-series-data)

Comment: @jpsmith I'm not sure that is a dupe - the problem here is that the data are date-time rather than date, whereas in that question the data appear to be factors. Hence the solutions of that question do not directly answer this one.

Comment: @CaptainHat thanks for pointing that out! The [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28741027/12109788) worked when I tested with `abline(v = as.numeric(plot_data2$Date[1]), lwd=2, col='red')`, but realize now they are inputing the lines manually, not derived from the data. Excellent catch! I I retracted my close vote but will leave the link to the other SO question for posterity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you `Date` column is a date time not a date. Hence, convert it to a date or use date times as "x" values for the vertical lines, i.e. use `as.POSIXct` instead of `as.Date`:

```r
plot(plot_data2$Date, plot_data2$Profitshare,
  type = "l", yaxt = "n",
  col = "blue", xlab = "Date", 
  ylab = "Value", ylim = c(0.05, 0.15)
)
# lines(
#   indexprofitshare$Date[indexprofitshare$Date >= as.Date("2020-01-01")],
#   indexprofitshare$Counterfactual[indexprofitshare$Date >= as.Date("2020-01-01")],
#   type = "l", col = "red", lty = 2
# )
legend("bottomright",
  legend = c("Profitshare", "Counterfactual"),
  col = c("blue", "red"), lty = c(1, 2)
)
axis(
  side = 2, at = pretty(c(0.06, 0.14)),
  labels = paste0(pretty(c(0.06, 0.14) * 100), "%"), las = 1
)
abline(
  v = c(as.POSIXct("2022-01-01"), as.POSIXct("2023-01-31")),
  col = c("blue", "red"), 
  lty = c(1, 2), 
  lwd = c(1, 3)
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. it works!

My only problem now is that the two vertical lines go beyond the limits of the graph abover and below...

Comment: Try adding `xpd = FALSE` to your `abline` command, ie,  `abline(..., xpd = FALSE)` and see if that works

Comment: In `lines...` also need `as.POSIXct("2020-01-01")`, and print `legend` at the end to avoid overlap.